# Allow customers to remove their product reviews in Magento

Tags: magento, review

I've not been able to find anything. No built-in functionality, no modules, and nothing about anyone trying to do this. Now, the reason I need to know this is because I have a customer that would like this functionality.

How do I add a link in the "My reviews" page when a user/ customer is logged in, that allows them to remove their reviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own module with a controller which is able to delete specific reviews. To start, take a look how this is done in the admin where the admin can delete reviews.
You can use layout xml to add a new section "My reviews" to the user area. When the user clicks on it, you should use your indexAction in your controller to render all those reviews which belong to the user in the session.
This definitely needs quite a bit custom coding experience.

Comment: I take it there is no module out there already then.
Thanks for your reply. And also, thanks for the hint.